# How to escape double quotes and exclamation mark in password?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have the following code:

```
curl -s --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"$1\",\"password\":\"$2\"}" http://apiurl
```

In the above `curl` command I want to escape the `"` and `!` in the password. Right now the password is just given as `$2`

I have modified the curl command as below but it doesn't seem to work

```
curl -s --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"$1\",\"password\":\"$2\"}" http://apiurl
```

Comment: How does it not work? Error? Not the output you expect?  What is in `$1` and `$2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to generate JSON manually; use a program like `jq`, which knows how to escape things properly, to generate it for you.

```
json=$(jq -n --arg u "$1" --arg p "$2" '{username: $u, password: $p}')
curl -s --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$json" http://apiurl
```

Comment: thanks. but I have around 100 servers wherein I will be uploading this script. What if jq is not installed on some of them?

Comment: You have a requirement to work with JSON: make sure the tools you need *are* installed.